# WCF callbacks received by one PC and missed on two others

Tags: c#, wcf

There is a NET 4 WCF service (in a remote server) that I am connecting to from my NET 4 client application. The service implements callbacks and my client application is able to successfully call methods and receive callbacks. Just perfect.

Now, if I copy the executable (and config) to the remote server where WCF service is hosted (standalone), the application can execute methods successfully but it NEVER receives any callbacks!

I also tried running the application off a virtual machine on my development PC. It was too able to connect to the service and execute methods but once again NEVER receive any callbacks!

I have tried the ultimate test. I have run the application in all 3 places at the same time. All 3 initialize fine and call the methods on the service successfully but as soon as event is triggered, only my development PC receives the callback! The other two go silent. All 3 apps were started from a single shared folder so effectively run the same code and rely on the same config.

What is my development PC so special to be the only one to receive the callbacks? Any clues are more than welcome. I am hoping this will ring a bell to someone.

[Update]

After enabling tracing I found the following exception. It seems that some internal buffer limits were hit. I am not sure how to fix that. These are some of my current limits from app.config: `maxBufferPoolSize="16384000" maxReceivedMessageSize="16384000"`.

*The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:result. The InnerException message was 'There was an error deserializing the object of type MatchResult. The maximum array length quota (16384) has been exceeded while reading XML data. This quota may be increased by changing the MaxArrayLength property on the XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas object used when creating the XML reader.'.  Please see InnerException for more details.*

Comment: Enable [WCF Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx). you can then view the trace file via the [Service Trace Viewer Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023.aspx). That should help out a lot in your debugging.

Comment: Thanks Scott. I have enabled tracing per your advice and found some clues. The question is now updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Googling on MaxArrayLength [revealed this](http://davidsandor.com/post/2010/05/24/Setting-maxArrayLength-value-for-a-customBinding-using-binaryMessageEncoding.aspx) which seems to do the trick. Hope this helps somebody and saves them hours of going mad.

I am quoting the important bits in case the blog goes down.

```
<binding name="MaintenanceServiceBindingConfiguration">
  <binaryMessageEncoding>
      <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" />
  </binaryMessageEncoding>
  <httpTransport maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
          maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" />
</binding>
```